# Automatic movement to an activity with out any intents in android

Tags: android

I have developed an application in android and also deployed in the mobile.

While running,one activity is getting refreshing sometimes.When I am working in other activities also,the control is automatically moving to that specific activity.

I am not using any intents and also did'nt write any special functionality for that.

I am new to android and not able to solve this.Please help me solve this.

Anyone answer this please..........

In my application I have an activity named,security.java.It is getting reloaded again and again even if am not doing that.When I am using other activities also,it is moving to activity security.java.Even I am not using any intents also.I dont understand how to solve it.Am I clear,or need to explain in more detail.This answer is very important for me.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Please any one suggest me if have any idea about this issue.

Comment: @sushma you will have to be very specific about your problem, else your question will be closed soon.

Comment: In my application I have an activity named,security.java.It is getting reloaded again and again even if am not doing that.When I am using other activities also,it is moving to activity security.java.Even I am not using any intents also.I dont understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey u need to understand android life cycle. Here is the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

I think that ur security.java might not be getting destroyed. And you can see it again when ur other activity finishes. Study the life cycle n detect where the problem is

Comment: But I don't use any services in my application.......

Comment: hey sorry I meant security.java, sorry for the stupid mistake and u need to be more specific like expose some part of your code to get better help